# Unable to insert into PostgreSQL using laravel eloquent ORM

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I did my research a lot before posting this.

I am getting the following error when trying to insert a record into PostgreSQL using Laravel eloquent ORM.

This is the error:

```
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException

SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 
7 ERROR: column "id" does not exist LINE 1: ...ed_at", "created_at") 
values ($1, $2, $3, $4) 
returning "id" ^ (SQL: insert into "fb_post_like_counts" ("post_id", "count", "updated_at", "created_at") values (293843523498_10152007721598499, 0, 2014-03-12 16:56:24, 2014-03-12 16:56:24) returning "id")
```

This is the database table create schema:

```
Schema::create('fb_post_shares_counts', function($table)
{
    //
    $table->string('post_id');
    $table->string('count')->default(0);

    //  created_at updated_at deleted_at
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();

    // set composite keys   
    $table->primary(array('post_id', 'updated_at'));
});
```

and this is the code i am trying to execute:

```
// SAVE POST SHARES
$post_share_count   =   new FbPostShareCount;
$post_share_count->post_id   =  $response['id'];
$post_share_count->count    =   $fql_post['share_count'];       
$post_share_count->save();
```

and I created a model class FbPostShareCount extends Eloquent.

I know that laravel does not support complex keys but this problem did not occur when I was using MySQL

Comment: Awaiting feedback. Is it solved?

Answer (score 13):

Set the primary key in your `FbPostShareCount` model as

```
class FbPostShareCount extends Eloquent {

    protected $primaryKey = 'post_id';

    ...
}
```

Comment: same error. Just for the record I am using composite keys in the database I attached the schema.

Comment: as far as I'm aware eloquent does not currently support composite keys.

Comment: @MoFetch The [Antonio Carlos Ribeiro](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22362532/2595536) is right. But, as [arcsum](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23731829/2595536) also has said, it should be INTEGER as ID for PK.

Answer (score 4):

Laravel eloquent ORM have auto increment, So set up primaryKey = null and increment = false.

```
protected $primaryKey = null;

public $incrementing = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using the correct data type for post id?

```
$table->integer('post_id');
```